# NoReverseMatch for rendering a form

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to prepopulate the fields in a form from database.
I have an html page and there is a table at which I will click on the link which will render the html form with values populated from the database.

But the issue is: I am not able to prepopulate the HTML form fields.
Following is my code and I am not able to get the output.

html code in table

```
<td>{{ info.university_code }}</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_grescore }}</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_english_score }}</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_undergradcgpa }} CGPA</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_workex_months }} Months</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_research_skills }}%</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_acceptancepercentage }}</td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'editSummary' univ_code=info.university_code  %}"
```

Views.py(here all my logic is present which is notworking and gives me an error)

```
def editSummary(request,univ_code):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UniversitySummaryForm(request.POST or None, instance =   
        uiversity)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/AdminHome')

        else:
            form = UniversityInfoForm()

            form.fields["university_code"].queryset =UniversityNames.objects.filter(university_code=request.university_code)

    template_vars = RequestContext(request, {
        "form": form,
        "university_code": request.university_code
    })
    return render_to_response(
        "PredictiveAcceptance/AdminUniversitySummary.html",
        template_vars)
```

Models.py (for database fields)

```
class UniversitySummaries(models.Model):
    university_code = models.ForeignKey('UniversityNames',
        models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='university_code', primary_key=True)
    avg_grescore = models.IntegerField()
    avg_english_score = models.IntegerField()
    avg_undergradcgpa = models.IntegerField()
    avg_workex_months = models.IntegerField()
    avg_research_skills = models.IntegerField()
    avg_acceptancepercentage = models.IntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Forms.py file

```
class UniversitySummaryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UniversitySummaries
        fields = ('university_code', 'avg_grescore',
            'avg_english_score', 'avg_undergradcgpa', 'avg_workex_months',
            'avg_research_skills', 'avg_acceptancepercentage')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^AdminHome/$', AdminSiteViews.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^AdminListOfUniversity/$', AdminSiteViews.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^AdminUniversitySummary/$', AdminSiteViews.summary, name='summary'),
    url(r'^editSummary/<univ_code>/$', AdminSiteViews.editSummary, name='editSummary'),
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twIt0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uUA1.png)

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question. It indicates that the URL resolver could not build a link (probably the code `url 'editSummary' univ_code=info.university_code` in your template, but the error message is needed to ascertain it).

Comment: If you get a `NoReverseMatch` error then you need to show the full error, and the urls.py that includes `editSummary`.

Comment: Note that `render_to_response` is obsolete, you should use `render(request, template, {...})` instead. If you’re running an older version of Django, you really should upgrade to the latest release or latest LTS 1.11x.

Comment: Kindly help I updated the problem with the error. @Alasdair

Comment: Please check @Risadinha

Comment: If you just want to copy the line "Exception Value" from the first image into this question here as text - that would be immensely helpful because it is then searchable for anyone else. Also, it tells you what the problem is, exactly: the value of `univ_code` is not correct.

Comment: Could you get me with the solution I have tried a lot of things and not able to get the values populated in the HTML form fields.
Apologies for incorrect posting, I am not used to this.

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the form itself. Instead, the template contains an URL tag with a resolver call, and this fails. The resolver cannot create the URL for this tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'editSummary' univ_code=info.university_code  %}"
```

You are using the object representation of the foreign key as the value to `univ_code` here but `info.university_code` is the string representation of an object of type `UniversityNames`.

```
university_code = models.ForeignKey('UniversityNames',
    models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='university_code', primary_key=True)
```

You have not posted the model but I suppose the url tag should look like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'editSummary' univ_code=info.university_code.university_code  %}"
```

deduced from this line in your code:

```
UniversityNames.objects.filter(university_code=request.university_code)
```

Comment: I tried using the code provided by you still its not working. thanks for your response.
Could you explain in detail.  @Risadinha

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called `info` in your template, so you can't use `info.university_code` as a parameter to the `url` tag.

You could fix it by just doing `{% url 'editSummary' univ_code=university_code %}`, but the rest of your template would still be broken.

Comment: "info" is the for loop variable which I used for populating all the rows in the table.

Comment: What for loop? Show the rest of the template. But you don't seem to be passing anything that could be iterated through anyway.

Comment: <tbody>  
       {% for info in UniversityObj %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ info.university_code }}</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_grescore }}</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_english_score }}</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_undergradcgpa }} CGPA</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_workex_months }} Months</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_research_skills }}%</td>
         <td>{{ info.avg_acceptancepercentage }}</td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'editSummary' univ_code=info.university_code.university_code  %}" style="color:black">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
       {% endfor %}

Comment: Sigh. You don't have anything called UniversityObj in that template either.